# Why did my laptop screen go white?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure

Today I was working on my Samsung NP300E5E Laptop, and the screen suddenly turned white. I tried to reboot, it was still white, I couldn't see BIOS or anything, except it showed the Samsung logo (the one that normally appears for a few seconds whenever you turn the device on) and then it went white again.

One year ago the screen has been damaged before leaving behind a black strip on the corner, but that was not much of a problem to me, the black strip/spot has been there for over a year, and I lived with it. But now that the whole screen turned white, I totally can't see anything.

I tried to plug in an external monitor via HDMI, and it worked, and I was able to log in the Windows and everything seemed normal, nonetheless the main problem was not fixed. I read many forums and they all suggest that the video cable or screen might be damaged, but I ruled these out since I was able to see the Samsung logo at the beginning, and I tried to press <kbd>F2</kbd> (when the logo screen appeared), I could see the BIOS setup screen for a second, but then it went white again.

I don't think it's cable problem, video card problem or screen problem, since external monitors works and the screen does actually work at beginning (at least for a few seconds). And by the way, the screen only turns on temporarily on the logo, and only the logo, so it's not that it got fixed because I moved or twisted the cable a little. It was totally independent of the cable. The logo keeps appearing every time I turn the laptop on.

What could the problem be? Can I do anything else to diagnose it?